# How can I get a id type belong to which type

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I get a id type belong to which type. and depend the type to do different method

```
-(id)initWithImage:(id)texture
{
   if(texure == NSString)
    {
       do fun1;
    }

     if(texture == NSMutableArray)
     {
       do fun2;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[texture isMemberOfClass: [NSString class]]`

(or isKindOfClass if you want to return YES for Subclasses too)